# Перенос елементов в RecyclerView на новую строку

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Есть андроид приложение со страничкой аккаунта, на которой есть RecyclerView, который в свою очередь содержит скиллы, которыми обладает пользователь

Проблема в том, что RecyclerView позволяет скролить данные по горизонтали или по вертикали, то есть сейчас ситуация вот такая 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, для доступа к данным которые не влазят на экран, необходимо скролить

А мне нужно что бы эти данные заполняли пространоство как показано на картинке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли это с использованием RecyclerView или надо использовать что то еще?

Comment: Вам должен помочь [FlexboxLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html)

Comment: Можно. Только используйте не LinearLayoutManager, a GridLayoutManager y RecyclerView.

Comment: @eugennek спасибо помогло)